# BlackBerry 10 WebWorks BlackBerry 10 PhoneGap WebView URL

Tags: cordova, blackberry, webview, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

We are currently developing a phonegap application using BlackBerry WebWorks SDK and we are currently not able to access or control the WebView and its URL.

It is basically loading Index.html page which I dont want. I want to load some external URL on the server which then once authenticated loads index.html of the www folder. This is not working. Any Idea how to control the WebView URL?

Thanks,
Ankit Tanna

Answer (score 0):

I just developed an app with WebWorks 2.1 / Cordova and encountered the same challenge.

First, my goal was to go cross-platform, so I'm using the [InAppBrowser](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) plugin (though to be honest, I'm not sure if that has to be included manually).

The BlackBerry 10 WebView doesn't seem to support the loadstart and exit events, so you have to use a timer to manually check the state of the WebView. Something like this:

```
var VIEWER = window.open('http://myauthenticationpage/login.html', '_blank', 'location=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,status=no');

//Start a timer to check for a URL change in the WebView
var AuthTimer = setInterval(function () {

    //Handle your failure case your own way, but stopping this loop is a good idea if the WebView isn't open
    if ((typeof VIEWER === 'undefined') || (typeof VIEWER.document === 'undefined')) {
        clearInterval(AuthTimer);
        return; 
    }

    //Get the current URL of the WebView
    var url = VIEWER.document.URL;

    //Process the URL in some way, like to extract a token
    //You can also access the DOM of the loaded page, as another option
    if (url.indexOf('authorizedUser=') > 0) {
        //Extract the username, which my server appends in the query string 
        var user = url.substring(url.indexOf('authorizedUser=') + 15);

        //I store the user token in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('user', user);

        //Close the viewer and stope this timer
        clearInterval(AuthTimer);
        VIEWER.close();
    }
}, 20);
```

After doing this, you may have to do an ajax call to the server to get a user token or some other information...depends on your implementation.

So when your app starts, your first page should immediatly do a check: do I have a stored user token? If not, kick off the above process. Continue to kick it off until I have a stored user token. When I have a token, begin loading user data from the server, or load index.html from www/, or whatever you want to do.

This works well for me and the devices handle it well.

**Note for Android/iOS**

If you decide to take it cross platform to Android or iOS, you can do this using events instead:

```
var VIEWER = window.open('http://myauthenticationpage/login.html', '_blank', 'location=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,status=no');

VIEWER.addEventListener('exit', function(e) {
    //The webview closed!
    if (user == null) {
        //We still don't have a username
        setTimeout(function () {
            //Kick open the webview again, to try again for a username for example
            //(Might want to wrap all this in a function)
            VIEWER = window.open('http://myauthenticationpage/login.html', '_blank', 'location=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,status=no');
        }, 50);
    }
});

VIEWER.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e) {
    //The webview has started loading a new page
    var url = e.url;
    var user = null;

    if (url.indexOf('authorizedUser=') > 0) {
        user = url.substring(url.indexOf('authorizedUser=') + 15);

        localStorage.setItem('user', user);

        VIEWER.close();
    }
});
```

Using this technique, your web page will need to 'echo' back some data in the query string or response DOM when a successful login occurs. I think for most authorization implementations, just set a dummy callback URL in your request then just watch for the callback URL in the WebView url..

I hope this helps!

John